# How to create a value changed call back for a numeric field using App Designer?

Tags: matlab

The Mathworks guide has not helped me much with this...

I am creating this GUI and what I want to do is when I enter in a new value for a parameter in my GUI it will change the value in my workspace corresponding to whatever I entered in the app.

I created the app and dropped a quick field box on it and I added a value changed callback.

I added a public property into the app as:

```
properties (Access = public)
    Tview
end
```

Then for the callback I have:

```
function TviewEditFieldValueChanged(app, event)
    app.Tview = app.TviewEditField.Value;
    app.app1.Value = app.Tview;
end
```

The name of my app right now is `app1` while the parameter I am manipulating is `Tview`

Then in my source code I have:

```
Tview = app.Tview;
```

When I run the app and input a number and hit enter I get this error:

```
"No appropriate method, property, or field 'app1' for class 'app1'."
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Comment: The error comes from your line: `app.app1.Value = app.Tview;`. In this function, your app is only called `app` (*NOT* `app1`), because that how you defined it in the input parameter name of the function. Anyway, what are you trying to assign on this line ?

Comment: @Hoki I am trying to say that the value assigned in that numeric field is the value for my variable Tview in my source code.

Comment: ok, but the error message tells you there is no such numeric field. `app.Tview` does exist, but `app.app1.Value` does not. Assign your `app.Tview`value to an existing field and you'll be all right.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use *evalin* or *assignin* as follow. The example I show is in the callback of a ButtonPushed

```
function ButtonPushed(app, event)
  AppVar1 = 12;
  evalin('base', ['WorkspaceVar1 = ', num2str(AppVar1), ';']);
  AppVar2 = 24;
  assignin('base', 'WorkspaceVar2', AppVar2);
end
```

Where *base* is the workspace base directory.